# drupal - call a menu from a template

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm having trouble calling a menu I created from inside a template. I have reasons not to use the blocks admin page or context for this.

```
<?php $block = module_invoke('menu', 'block_view', 'menu-core-helpful-links'); print render($block['content']); ?>
```

The menu I created is named helpful links. On the block config page I hover over the configure link and see the machine name is "menu-core-helpful-links" but this doesn't work, so how can I do this? Or can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had created the menu and went back and had changed the name. the new name appeared in the block admin page, but hovering over the edit menu link in menu admin, I saw the machine name was the old one. Once I used that, it worked fine.